# Switching hexadecimal symbols in a byte

Tags: java, hex, switch-statement, bit-manipulation

I want to switch the two hexadecimals symbols in a byte, for example if

```
input  = 0xEA
```

then

```
output = 0xAE
```

It has to be in java.

I already have this method I made, but it only works in some cases:

```
public static final byte convert(byte in){

    byte hex1 = (byte) (in <<  4);
    byte hex2 = (byte) (in >>> 4);

    return (byte) (hex1 | hex2);
}
```

A working example is:

```
input:  0x3A 
hex1:   0xA0
hex2:   0x03
output: 0xA3
```

A not working example is:

```
input:  0xEA
hex1:   0xA0
hex2:   0xFE
output: 0xFE
```

Anyone can shed some lights on why this is not working?

Comment: I'm not much of a Java programmer but think a byte is signed. Try using an integer for the intermediate steps and see how it goes, although there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the problem is the sign extension.  Specifically, you probably need to do

```
byte hex2 = (byte) ((in >>> 4) & 0xF);
```

Comment: ok, that works, thank you very much!! but shouldn't '>>>' do that already?

Comment: `>>>` doesn't introduce any _new_ negative sign bits, but you already had a bunch of leading `1` bits that got shifted in.  Think of it this way: first your byte got sign-extended to 32 bits -- so if it was initially negative, it got 24 new `1` bits -- and then you shifted _those_ over.

Comment: yep makes sense, just not used to signed bytes nor with bitwise operations returning integers. I guess Java was not the best choice for this kind of work... But again, THANK YOU very much!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    byte hex1 = (byte) (in <<  4);
    byte hex2 = (byte) ( in >>> 4);
    return (byte) (hex1 | hex2 & 0x0F);
```

this is like in a known puzzle

```
    byte x = (byte)0xFF;
    x = (byte) (x >>> 1);
    System.out.println(x);
```

prints `-1` because before unsigned shift 0xFF is promoted to int -> 0xFFFFFFFF; after shift it is 0x7FFFFFFF; cast to byte -> 0xFF

but

```
    byte x = (byte)0xFF;
    x = (byte) ((x & 0xFF) >>> 1);
    System.out.println(x);
```

prints `127` because we truncated 0xFFFFFFFF  -> 0x000000FF, now shift produces 0x0000007F, cast to byte -> 0x7F

Actually, this promotion is done at compile time. JVM works only with 4 or 8 bytes operands (local variables on stack). Even boolean in bytecode is 0 or 1 int.